# Where did I go wrong with my odd proof that $\frac{3dx}{3x} = \frac{5dx}{5x} \iff 3=5$?

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

I don't know where I went wrong, but it's interesting for me. Please check where my fault is! 
It is obvious that the below equation is correct:

$$\frac{3dx}{3x}=\frac{5dx}{5x}$$
$$u=3x$$and$$v=5x$$
$$\frac{du}{u}=\frac{dv}{v}$$
integrate both sides:
$$ln(u)=ln(v)$$
$$u=v$$
$$3x=5x$$
so, 
$$3=5$$

Comment: You went wrong integrating both sides

Comment: When you integrate both sides you need your constant of integration. 
 "+C"

Comment: Forgot the constant of integration

Comment: An excellent example of the importance of remembering the constant of integration. I will certainly use this as an example when I teach integration ....

Comment: 3 *does* equal 5.  ... plus a constant.

Comment: @fleablood In this case multiplied by a constant.

Comment: There are quite a lot of duplicates. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079111/integrate-1-x-by-parts) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424854/1-0-by-integration-by-parts-of-tanx) [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434589/why-does-integration-by-parts-yield-0-1-here).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Integrating we obtain

$$\ln(u)=\ln(v)+ C$$

Comment: Where $C = \ln u - \ln v = \ln \frac{u}{v}$ So, $\ln u = \ln \left(v \cdot \frac{u}{v}\right)$, giving us $3 = 5 \cdot \frac{3}{5}$..Spelling out what you were implying.

Comment: @Davislor I'm not implying nothing! I just gave the answer to the OP that is "I don't know where I went wrong". You are free to add your own answer here below with all the details you like. Morover try to be polite when you formulate any kind of request.

Comment: Sorry to have sounded impolite! I just wanted to acknowledge that you were aware of the steps you left out.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for the clarification. I would like to proceed as in the answer here below exponentiating both sides to obtain $u=kv$ wiith $k=e^C=3/5$. Let add your own answer if you like to suggest another way. Bye

Answer (score 8):

If you're taking an indefinite integral, then you need to include constants. Integrating, we get $\ln(u)+C_1 = ln(v)+C_2$. We can collect $C_1$ and $C_2$ into one constant by setting $C_3 = C_2-C_1$, getting  $\ln(u) = ln(v)+C_3$. We can then exponentiate both sides, getting $u=ve^{C_3}$. Setting $C_4=e^{C_3}$, this becomes $u=C_4v$. In this case, $C_4$ is $\frac35$.

If you're taking definite integrals, you need to include the limits. Suppose we integrate starting from $x = 1$. Then $u$ starts at $3$. So when we integrate $\frac{du}u$, we have $\ln(u)$ at the upper limit, but we have to subtract $\ln$ of the lower limit, and the lower limit is $3$. So we have that the definite integral is $\ln(u)-\ln(3)=\ln(\frac u3)$. Similarly, for $v$, we get that the definite integral is $\ln(\frac v 5)$. Plugging in $u=3x$ and $v=5x$, we get $\ln(\frac {3x}3)=\ln(\frac {5x} 5)$, which simplifies to $\ln(x)=\ln(x)$.

Comment: After setting $C_3$, the LHS is just $ln(u)$

Answer (score 6):

To turn my comment into an answer, your proof is correct up to the step
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{u} = \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{v} $$

At that point, as others have said, you forget to add the constants of integration when you integrate:

$$ \ln u + \mathrm{C_1} = \ln v + \mathrm{C_2} $$

Substituting $\mathrm{C} = \mathrm{C}_2 - \mathrm{C}_1$ gives us:

$$\begin{align}
\ln u &= \ln v + \mathrm{C} \\
\ln u - \ln v &= \mathrm{C} \\
\end{align}$$

Substituting for $\mathrm{C}$ in the first equation just gets us $\ln u = \ln u$, which is clearly no contradiction. A little more interesting, perhaps, is to turn our identity for $\mathrm{C}$, $\ln u - \ln v$, into $\ln \frac{u}{v}$ and then substitute that into the other equation above to get:

$$\begin{align}
 \ln u &= \ln v + \ln \frac{u}{v} \\
         &= \ln \left( v \cdot \frac{u}{v} \right)
\end{align}$$

Now take the exponential of both sides.

$$\begin{align}
u &= v \cdot \frac{u}{v} \\
3x &= 5x \cdot \frac{3x}{5x} \\
3 &= 5 \cdot \frac{3}{5}
\end{align}$$

This is presumably what Serge Seredenko meant when he said in his comment that 3 is equal to 5, “[i]n this case multiplied by a constant.”