# Special case of this general integral

Tags: integration

We know that the integral of,

$$ \int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln x$$

ignoring any integration constants.

Consider the integral of some more `general' function,

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^z +z^2}} dx $$

i.e. in the $y=z=0$ case we recover the original integral ($1/x$)

Now, if I put the second integral into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%201%2F(x%5E2%20%2By%5E2%20%2Bz%5E2)%5E0.5%20dx), it spits out,

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^z +z^2}} dx = \ln \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} + x\right)$$.

I naively expected that in the $y=z=0$ case, this answer would revert to $\ln x$, but instead we get $\ln 2x$

What gives?

Comment: Technically it's $\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln|x|+C$, where the locally constant function $C$ can have different values for the cases $x<0,\,x>0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

$$\ln 2x=\ln x +\ln 2=\ln x +C$$

Comment: Hmmm ok, but if I wanted to evaluate both over some limits $x=x_1 \rightarrow x_2$, it seems I would still get different answers?

Comment: @user1887919 No since the constant cancels out, let try also  with some numerical example.

Comment: @user1887919 You are welcome! Refer also to that related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2878783/505767), Bye